# Selenium WebDriver with Jenkins

Tags: java, selenium, jenkins, selenium-webdriver, jenkins-plugins

I'm looking into using Selenium WebDriver with Jenkins. We have a Jenkins server running under Windows Server 2008 and would like to run all my test cases and I'm using mstest and also i have installed VS on the windows server... Here is the list of plugin I have installed on my server:

```
Selenium Auto Exec Server(AES) plugin
This plugin is for continuous regression test by Selenium Auto Exec Server (AES).      0.5          

Jenkins Selenium Builder plugin
1.1         

Hudson Seleniumhq plugin
This plugin integrates Seleniumhq to Hudson.
0.4         

Selenium HTML report
0.94            

SeleniumRC plugin
This plugin allows you to create Selenium server instance for each project build.
1.0
```

Are there any plugins to installed on Jenkins?

**EDIT**

This is what I am using to instantiated my driver, do I have to use `RemoteDriver`?

```
public static IWebDriver GetDriver()
{
    string _url = new Uri(Common.Url).DnsSafeHost.ToString(); 

     switch (Common.BrowserSelected)
     {
         case "ff":
         FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
         profile.SetPreference("network.http.phishy-userpass-length", 255);
         profile.SetPreference("network.automatic-ntlm-auth.trusted-uris", _url);
         drv = new FirefoxDriver(profile);
                    break;
          case "ie":
          var options = new InternetExplorerOptions();
           options.IntroduceInstabilityByIgnoringProtectedModeSettings = true;
           DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
            capabilities.SetCapability(CapabilityType.AcceptSslCertificates, true);
                    drv = new InternetExplorerDriver(options);
                    break;
                case "chrome":
                    //_driver = new ChromeDriver();
                    break;
            }
            return drv;
        }
```

Comment: I would strongly advise you use ''RemoteDriver'', it pays off in the long run.

Comment: how? would you expand your suggestions

Answer (score 1):

*Are there any plugins to installed on Jenkins?*

-No, you do not need these plugins.

*This is what I am using to instantiated my driver, do I have to use `RemoteDriver`?*

I think you need `RemoteDriver` for executing your test, and you need add initialization for this `RemoteDriver` in `GetDriver()` function.

May be you help this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12836114/selenium-webdriver-remote-setup) and [this](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/Grid2)

My Config:

```
firefox {
    capability = DesiredCapabilities.firefox()
    capability.setPlatform(Platform.LINUX)
    driver = {new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://some.domain:4444/wd/hub"), capability)}
}
```

So I use [Geb](http://www.gebish.org) for testing, but I think there is no difference.

Comment: i'm not sure if i follow your solution, so there are two parts to it the `first part is what plug-ins do i need in order to run the selenium test cases in jenkins? ` the second part i will update my question.

Comment: how do you check the `environments`  ?

Comment: can you throw me a code to initialization for remotedriver? do i need selenium grid for that?